# regex modify backslash

Tags: php, regex

How could I modify this regex:

```
preg_match_all('/\[startstring\](.*?)\[endstring\]/s', $input, $matches);
```

to look for `@` instead of `[startstring]`, and `;` instead of `[endstring]`?

When I try this:

```
preg_match_all('/\@\(.*?)\=(.*?)\;\/s', $input, $matches);
```

it doesn't work. :( It says something like `No ending delimiter '/' found in /home/content/76/7290476/html/newr.php on line 3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You escaped the final backslash for some reason.  You're also escaping `@` and `;`, which is unnecessary:

```
#@(.*?)=(.*?);#s
```

You don't have to use the slash as a delimeter (above, I used `#`).  Be careful about escaping characters that you shouldn't.  I don't think you intended to escape that first paren either.

Comment: I guess you could remove the starting `'` from the regex or put one at the end to indicate that it is a string. Just nitpicking but it got my ocd sense tingling. +1 for the good answer though.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté thanks for pointing that out; you can go ahead and edit answers to fix minor details like that on your own

Comment: Yes, I usually do that. But an unpaired apostrophe removal isn't a minor thing considering chaos theory. `:P` lol ok, next time I'll remove it.